# Website Hosting Virtualbox Ubuntu Server 18.04

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, apache2, url

I am a freelance part time website builder (yeah I know, try to stop laughing). I want to host a website on my VirtualBox (6), running Ubuntu server 18.04, so I (and or a client) can see a site I am working on outside of my network. It has Pihole running on it (it being the VirtualBox Ubuntu 18.04 server). I installed Apache2, php, and mysql. I got an error on startup and had to change the listening port. I opened the changed port on my router. The router is behind the AT&T modem/router. I have open the port there as well. Now I get no errors at start up or apache2 restart. This is on my desktop OS Ubuntu 18.04. I followed instructions to set up the server and point the URL to my IP.

I bought a domain (call it example.com) at Godaddy and pointed the URL to my IP. When I type the URL into a browser, it shows the Apache2 it's working page as expected. What was not expected, the page showing was not the VirtualBox Unbuntu 18.04 server - Apache2 index.html page. After a few hours of trying to figure out where the index.html page was that was showing in the browser was, I found it in my desktop. I didn't even know my desktop had apache2 installed (DOH!). I don't want to open my desktop to internet traffic, so...

My question is: How do I get the URL to show the index.html page in the VirtualBox Ubuntu 18.04 Apache2 server, not the desktop Apache2 server?

UPDATE : My temporary workaround "ngrok"

I am still unable to use the URL purchased for this VirtualBox machine, however I found a workaround. The software is at ngrok dot com. The basic services are free. What ngrok does is create a secure tunnel to your localhost. When you run ngrok client, it binds your IP with a URL it creates. It works well. The drawback is I get a new URL each time I start up my virtualBox machine.

So this solution will suffice until I actually solve my issue. Little help?

Comment: What kind of VirtualBox networking did you set up? NAT? Bridged? Something else?

Comment: Network Adapter 1: Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop (Bridged Adapter, enp2s0)

Comment: "Bridged" so the Guest gets it's IP address from the Router (instead of the Host)?

Comment: I think the guest got its IP from the router. It is static. Now the PiHole is set to assign the IP to each machine in my network.

Comment: Host and each Guest should have different IPs on the same network if I'm understanding you correctly. Example: Host=192.168.1.x, Guest=192.168.1.y. Look at your Router's port forwarding. In your description, seems like it's forwarding to the Host. It should be forwarding to the Guest.

Comment: The desktop or host Apache2 is listening on the default port 80. The guest is listening on a new port (call it xxyy). My network router is behind the At&T modem. I'll open port "xxyy" in the AT&T modem next.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105233/discussion-between-oneputtmike-and-user535733).

Comment: I have stopped the Apache2 service on my desktop until I solve this issue.